# How to customize the Search result page of SharePoint 2013 server by using display template?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, search-results, enterprise-search, display-template

I need to Customize the Sharepoint Server 2013 Search result page like this

[image]

I Referred the following links

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945138.aspx 
http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/

but I need more reference,Please Guide me to achieve this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I style the Search Results page?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/127947/how-do-i-style-the-search-results-page)